# undefined reference error when using standalone toolchain to build squid for android

Tags: gcc, makefile, android-ndk, cross-compiling, toolchain

I am trying to build squid-3.5.24 for android. I am using `android-ndk-r10e` for the build.
Here is my environment. Based off this: https://gist.github.com/nddrylliog/4688209

```
#!/bin/sh

# I put all my dev stuff in here
export DEV_PREFIX=$HOME/Documents

# Don't forget to adjust this to your NDK path
export ANDROID_NDK=$HOME/Android/android-ndk-r10e

export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi

# I chose the gcc-4.7 toolchain - works fine for me!
export ANDROID_PREFIX=$DEV_PREFIX/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8

# Apparently android-8 works fine, there are other versions, look them up
export SYSROOT=${ANDROID_PREFIX}/sysroot

export CROSS_PATH=${ANDROID_PREFIX}/bin/${CROSS_COMPILE}

# Non-exhaustive lists of compiler + binutils
# Depending on what you compile, you might need more binutils than that
export CPP=${CROSS_PATH}-cpp
export AR=${CROSS_PATH}-ar
export AS=${CROSS_PATH}-as
export NM=${CROSS_PATH}-nm
export CC=${CROSS_PATH}-gcc
export CXX=${CROSS_PATH}-g++
export LD=${CROSS_PATH}-ld
export RANLIB=${CROSS_PATH}-ranlib

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_PREFIX/bin
export PATH=$PATH:${SYSROOT}/usr/lib
# This is just an empty directory where I want the built objects to be installed
export PREFIX=${SYSROOT}

# Don't mix up .pc files from your host and build target
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig

# You can clone the full Android sources to get bionic if you want.. I didn't
# want to so I just got linker.h from here: http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/bionic
# Note that this was only required to build boehm-gc with dynamic linking support.
export CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} --sysroot=${SYSROOT} -I${SYSROOT}/usr/include -I${ANDROID_PREFIX}/include"
export LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -L${SYSROOT}/usr/lib -L${ANDROID_PREFIX}/lib"

./configure --host=${CROSS_COMPILE} --with-sysroot=${SYSROOT} --prefix=${PREFIX} --cache-file=squid.cache "$@"
```

`configure` completed successfully I ran `make` . During the compilation, I get this error:

```
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:535: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:565: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::put(char)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:587: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::flush()'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:535: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:565: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::put(char)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:587: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::flush()'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:565: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::put(char)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:587: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::flush()'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_facets.h:869: error: undefined reference to 'std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_facets.h:869: error: undefined reference to 'std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [basic_smb_lm_auth] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I think the error has to do with linker not being able to locate `libstdc++` or `libstdc++--v3` but these libraries exist in `sysroot/usr/lib` which was already provided to `ld`.

I have tried linking the libraries directly with `-lstdc++--v3` and `-lstdc++` but that seems to mess with `gcc` in configure.

Currently at my wits end, can anybody point me in the right direction?

Here is rest of output from `make`:

```
Making all in compat
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in lib
Making all in snmplib
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in rfcnb
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in smblib
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in ntlmauth
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in libltdl
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  all-am
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in scripts
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in icons
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in errors
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in doc
Making all in manuals
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in release-notes
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in helpers
Making all in basic_auth
Making all in DB
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in MSNT-multi-domain
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in NCSA
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in POP3
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in RADIUS
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in SMB
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in SMB_LM
/bin/sh ../../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link /Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++  -g -O2 -std=c++11  -L/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/sysroot/usr/lib -L/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/lib -o basic_smb_lm_auth msntauth.o valid.o ../../../lib/smblib/libsmblib.la ../../../lib/rfcnb/librfcnb.la ../../../lib/libmiscencoding.la ../../../compat/libcompat-squid.la  -lm 
libtool: link: /Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -g -O2 -std=c++11 -o basic_smb_lm_auth msntauth.o valid.o  -L/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/sysroot/usr/lib -L/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/lib ../../../lib/smblib/.libs/libsmblib.a ../../../lib/rfcnb/.libs/librfcnb.a ../../../lib/.libs/libmiscencoding.a ../../../compat/.libs/libcompat-squid.a -lm
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:535: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:565: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::put(char)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:587: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::flush()'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:535: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:565: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::put(char)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:587: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::flush()'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:565: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::put(char)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:587: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::flush()'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_facets.h:869: error: undefined reference to 'std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_facets.h:869: error: undefined reference to 'std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_facets.h:869: error: undefined reference to 'std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:565: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::put(char)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:587: error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::flush()'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:49: error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_bad_cast()'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:49: error: undefined reference to 'std::cerr'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:152: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::clear(std::_Ios_Iostate)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
msntauth.o(.ARM.extab.text._ZNSt6vectorI16domaincontrollerSaIS0_EED2Ev+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:249: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
msntauth.cc:56: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)'
msntauth.cc:56: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:419: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_begin_catch'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:426: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_rethrow'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:419: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_catch'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/vector.tcc:419: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_cleanup'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ext/new_allocator.h:124: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
msntauth.o(.ARM.extab.text._ZNSt6vectorI16domaincontrollerSaIS0_EE19_M_emplace_back_auxIIRKS0_EEEvDpOT_+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2208: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:583: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::swap(std::string&)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2208: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:583: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::swap(std::string&)'
msntauth.cc:56: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)'
msntauth.cc:56: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)'
msntauth.cc:97: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
msntauth.cc:98: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::find(char, unsigned int) const'
msntauth.cc:99: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::find(char, unsigned int) const'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:535: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2758: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_facets.h:869: error: undefined reference to 'std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
msntauth.cc:107: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
msntauth.cc:108: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:113: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:324: error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: error: undefined reference to '__cxa_end_cleanup'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_ios.h:49: error: undefined reference to 'std::__throw_bad_cast()'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&)'
msntauth.cc:115: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/ostream:113: error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: error: undefined reference to 'std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:539: error: undefined reference to 'std::cerr'
/Users/ozojiegerald/Documents/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/include/c++/4.8/iostream:74: error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
msntauth.cc:61: error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
msntauth.o(.ARM.extab.text.startup+0x0): error: undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [basic_smb_lm_auth] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

**UPDATE:** updated my ndk to `android-ndk-r13b` and the error persisted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html). They exist specifically for using the NDK with non-NDK build systems. They'll do the work of figuring out how to pass all the flags you need for you; you just need to invoke `clang++`.

You should also probably update your NDK. r10 is now three years old. Standalone toolchains didn't work all that well until fairly recently (r12, but you might as well upgrade to r13).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I updated my `ndk` to `android-ndk-r13b` and I still get the same error

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Thought you were already using a standalone toolchain rather than trying to build one yourself. I've expanded my answer to include the additional info.

Comment: Turns out the problem was that after I updated my `ndk` and made another toolchain, I needed to add `-lgnustl_shared`to the linker flags. That solved this particular issue. Got another error about a function not being declared but that's another problem entirely. Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you use a standalone toolchain with a modern NDK then `-lgnustl_shared` should be unnecessary. It's supposed to do that for you.

Comment: I thought so too but it was written here: [toolchain doc](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) that you have to explicitly link against `libgnustl_shared.so` to use the `gnustl` port. The compilation went for some minutes until it got here: [DiskIOStrategy](https://github.com/squid-cache/squid/blob/master/src/DiskIO/DiskIOStrategy.h). Android C++ port doesn't seem to have the headers used there yet.

Comment: Ah, that is right. It's only libc++ that doesn't require the manual effort. Never mind!